# Docker Windows 8 issue - containers not loading after restart

Tags: windows-8, docker

I am new to Docker. I installed Docker (including Kitematic) in my local Windows 8 machine. After Docker installation, I installed a Docker image and which is loading perfectly.

But, when I restarted my machine, I couldn't find the containers in Kitematic which were installed previously. So, I installed the Docker image again.

Is it problem with the Docker image or should we follow the same procedure to install the Docker images again and again after logging of the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reinstalling the image through kinematic, try instead the command-line with [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) (which you have also installed, as part as [docker toolbox](https://www.docker.com/docker-toolbox)):

```
docker-machine ls
docker-machine start amachine
docker-machine ssh amachine
```

Then in the ssh session, you should find back your image:

```
docker images
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check it and let you know.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above commands and I found the docker images existing.

Comment: @kir I suspect Kinematic is not yet able to display images on *any* machine, especially on Windows

Comment: Ohhk. So, the solution is to use the Docker Terminal to start the images isntead of Kitematic?

Comment: @KiranTej Yes, docker machine is more mature than Kinematic.